# How to run Multiple Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)?

Tags: excel

I need to run Multiple Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) in a Asthma/COPD STATS Chart. Gary's Student gave some much appreciated help with SUB NUMBER TWO. Is this possible, and how can I do it?

My code is as follows and works individually.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved

If Range("R7").Value > Range("F7").Value Then
    Range("R7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("Q5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        rv = r.Value
        'Peak Flow Doctor Warning
        If rv = 180 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If
        If rv = 120 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
        End If
        If rv >= 450 Then
            MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        rv = r.Value
        'Weight Gain Warning
        If rv = 90 Then
            MsgBox "''LIKELY TO EXACERBATE COPD SYMPTOMS''" & vbCrLf & "''CHRONIC ASTHMA OR EMPHYSEMA PROBABLE''", vbCritical, "WARNING"
        End If
        If rv = 95 Then
            MsgBox "''IF SWELLING IN ANKLES PROBABLE FLUID RETENTION''" & vbCrLf & "''POSSIBILITY OF HEART FAILURE IF UNATTENDED''", vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING"
        End If
      Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: halfer If you take another look you will see the code is different and the differences is what had it operational.

Comment: My apologies, Father Goose, votes retracted. By the way, it looks like the indentation in your answer needs repairing, would you edit?

Comment: halfer An honest mistake. I'm not sure about your indentation repair, being a new boy at exel and VBA it took considerable time, confusion and effort to get this code to work. As the old saying goes "if it an"t broke don't fix it"  so I'm reluctant to make any alteration. But if you think I can improve it, I'm all for learning.

Comment: See [my edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48030219/revisions). Code cannot just be pasted into a question/answer, it needs to be Markdown formatted. There's a widget in the editor toolbar that does that.

Comment: Sorry, I did say I'm a new boy, thanks for your advice, I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the Multiple Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) with the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81"))
        For Each r In rng

            'Peak Flow Doctor Warning

            Select Case r.Value
                Case 180
                    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
                Case 120
                    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
                Case Is >= 550
                    MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
            End Select
        Next r
    End If
       'OraKinetics needs to change to (Target, Range("C95:AD95"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93"))
        For Each r In rng

            'Weight Gain Warning

            Select Case r.Value
                Case 90
                    MsgBox "''LIKELY TO EXACERBATE COPD SYMPTOMS''" & vbCrLf & "''CHRONIC ASTHMA OR EMPHYSEMA PROBABLE''", vbCritical, "WARNING"
                Case 95
                    MsgBox "''IF SWELLING IN ANKLES PROBABLE FLUID RETENTION''" & vbCrLf & "''POSSIBILITY OF HEART FAILURE IF UNATTENDED''", vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING"
            End Select
        Next r
    End If

    'Change Best Peak Flow and Date Achieved

    If Range("R7").Value > Range("F7").Value Then
        Range("R7").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("F7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("Q5").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("K7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub
```